# Why does "enable-shared failed" happen on libjpeg build for os X?

Tags: python, macos, build

I'm trying to install libjpeg on os X to fix a problem with the Python Imaging Library JPEG setup.

I downloaded libjpeg from http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz

I then began to setup the config file

```
cp /usr/share/libtool/config.sub .
cp /usr/share/libtool/config.guess .
./configure –enable-shared
```

However, the enable-shared flag didn't seem to work.

```
$ ./configure –-enable-shared
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: –-enable-shared
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `–-enable-shared': machine `–-enable' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub –-enable-shared failed
```

I've done lot's of google searches and I can't figure out where the error is or how to work around this error.

Comment: By "Python JPEG setup", do you mean the Python Imaging Library (PIL)?  And, BTW, you may get more responses if you went back and mark as accepted answers to some of your previous questions (0% doesn't look good!).

Answer (score 3):

I had copied the code from a blog.

The flag character there was not a hyphem , it just looked like one:

```
ord("–")

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

I changed it to a proper hypen and it works fine.